# Outlier treatment in sales data comparisson

Tags: python, descriptive-statistics, pandas

I'm working for a webshop and I'm trying to compare month for month this year with same month last year.

In order to get a better picture of growth in revenue/loss in revenue I use z-scores to detect outliers in the transaction data. We have about 2000-3000 monthly orders and with my calculations we have 20-50 monthly outlier values according to the z-score method. I use Python for my calculations

Im not sure if it is the right decision to remove all transactions when the z-score is +3 or -3 because the values are correct. If I shouldn't remove the outliers, would I then convert them to the closest value over -3 and under +3?

The tricky parts is my data is of course affected if we for example have improved our website and therefore increased our average order value. Another thing can be if we one month have special offers on high value products it would affect the data too.

My question is if I am approaching my analysis the right way. If not, can anyone help me in the right direction :)

Comment: What's this about converting to z-scores between -3 and 3?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Can you further elaborate?

Comment: You said you wanted to convert a z-score of, say, 4, to a z-score between -3 and 3. Do you mean that if your z-scores go 2.8, 4.1, 3.5, you would make the latter two 2.8?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what i am asking. If it is the right decision to convert all transaction values that has a z-score over 3 to the closest value I have to 3 and the same with -3.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with that?

Comment: Trying to normalize the data set.
The problem we have is that we now and then get some really huge orders that makes a month look really good sales-wise when it has actually been really bad before the huge sales. So Im trying to find a solution to do a better comparison

Answer (score 0):

How common are these points? What percent of data is "outliers"? A true "outlier" is supposed to be exceedingly rare, not just somewhat uncommon.

That being said, what evidence do you have that your data is distributed in a Gaussian fashion? The z score method requires that the data have a Gaussian (normal) distribution. What does the distribution of your data look like? If it is Gaussian, the +3/-3 rule may still be a bad idea, because 0.3% of your data will still be thrown away. Doesn't sound like much? 0.3% of the USA's current population is over 900,000 people. Do that many people not matter? If you have a large data set, then distribution-based outlier rules might not be a good idea.

Why are you throwing out outliers? Are you presuming that they have no useful information? How do you know they have no useful information? Maybe the "outliers" actually have a pattern.

These are things to investigate.

Comment: The percent of data that is "outliers" varies from 0.5-2%. From your answer I assume I approach it the wrong way.

It is actually right skewed when using a histogram. 

I don't think I anywhere stated that the "outliers" should be removed but maybe should be normalized.

The issue we have is that we some months can be really low in revenue and then be "saved" by really huge orders we have now and then. So Im trying to figure out a fair way to do the month to month comparison. 

Do you have any suggestion for how to approach it?

Comment: Ouch, up to 2% of the data is "outliers"? What do you mean by "normalized"?

Comment: The first thing to do is check for seasonality and adjust. One way to do this is with random intercepts by month on a mixed-level model.